# FireBaseUI java

Tags: java, android, firebase

Всем привет. Пишу тестовое приложение на FireBase (Android+Java). Столкнулся вот с какой проблемой. Использую из FireBaseUI для регистрации/аутентификации (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui?hl=en&authuser=0). В качестве sign in method поставил гугл аккаунт и Email/password. Так вот. С google все без проблем работает и регистрация и аутентификация. А с email/password зарегистрировался без проблем. Зарегистрированные пользователь появился в firebase console, например test@mail.ru. Но, если я попытаюсь зайти под ранее зарегистрированным пользователем test@mail.ru, то у меня открывается форма регистрации. Хотя я ожидаю увидеть, что у меня просто попросит ввести пароль, т.к. этот пользователь уже был зарегистрирован ранее. Как исправить этот баг? Или я, может что-то упустил из виду, например не подключил какую-нибудь библиотеку?

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.IdpResponse;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.data.model.FirebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> signInLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<FirebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(FirebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult result) {
                    onSignInResult(result);
                }
            }
    );

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Logged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            signOut();
        }
    }

    private void onSignInResult(FirebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult result) {
        IdpResponse response = result.getIdpResponse();
        if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
            // Successfully signed in
            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, user.getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            if (response != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + response.getError(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void signOut(){
        AuthUI.getInstance()
                .signOut(this)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build());

// Create and launch sign-in intent
                        Intent signInIntent = AuthUI.getInstance()
                                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                                .build();
                        signInLauncher.launch(signInIntent);
                    }
                });

    }

    public void onClickLogout(View view) {
        signOut();
    }
}
```